# Why are the icons not displayed in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am trying to put icons for FAB and buttons. But the icons are not displayed.
I don't know if I am doing the right thing or not?! I just want to be able to use the following code to display the icons.

react native : 0.69.5

@rneui/base: ^0.0.0-edge.2

@rneui/themed: ^0.0.0-edge.2

react-native-vector-icons: ^9.2.0

‍‍‍‍`<FAB title="Add new box" upperCase icon={{ name: 'add', color: 'white' }/>`

I am sorry to ask this question, I think there are many similar questions, but because I was not successful, I asked too again.
I tried to enter it manually , Steps I did:

1. ‍‍‍‍`npm install --save react-native-vector-icons`
2. Copy the contents in the Fonts folder to `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`
3. Edit android/settings.gradle and added

```
 include ':react-native-vector-icons'
 project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

my settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'AwesomeProject'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')

include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')

if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
    include(":ReactAndroid")
    project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')
    include(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine")
    project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine')
}
```

4. Edit android/app/build.gradle

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

5. Edit android/app/src/main/java/MainApplication.java

```
package com.awesomeproject;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.config.ReactFeatureFlags;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.awesomeproject.newarchitecture.MainApplicationReactNativeHost;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          packages.add(new VectorIconsPackage());
          
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  private final ReactNativeHost mNewArchitectureNativeHost =
      new MainApplicationReactNativeHost(this);

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      return mNewArchitectureNativeHost;
    } else {
      return mReactNativeHost;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the TurboModule system
    ReactFeatureFlags.useTurboModules = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.awesomeproject.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: revert those changes and try [these steps](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android)(options with gradle only) provided in react-native-vector-icon docs

Comment: I followed the instructions. @ArnabXD

Answer (score 2):

This version of React Native no need config manual option.
just add in **react-native.config.js** file

```
module.exports = {dependencies: {
    'react-native-vector-icons': {
      platforms: {
        ios: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

and add in **android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Comment: Thank you . I tried this but still having problem. I want to use icons like this: ‍‍``icon={{ name: 'timer', type: 'ionicon', color: 'white' }}``

Comment: Add Icon like this : <Icon name="timer"  type: "ionicon" color: "white"  />